# Ionic 5 Edge Browser side menu not showing

Tags: angular, ionic5

I updated Ionic to version 5, started a new project from the 'sidemenu' template, in Microsoft Edge browser and in Internet Explorer Side Menu doesn't show when in full screen.

Comment: There is a place in your project named browserlist or something like that which contains the allowed browser, add explorer to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the fact that Ionic Framework v5 supports Edge 79+ (Chromium-based Edge). For a little while, this was not properly reflected on the docs site, but that has now been updated to make it clearer.

See the following GitHub issue: [bug: Sidemenu hidden on large screen when using Microsoft Edge](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20526)
See also: [Ionic Desktop Browsers](https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/browser-support#desktop-browsers)